# How do I use clear() on <div> element in Cypress?

Tags: javascript, cypress

In my cypress tests, I need to modify a div form. I cannot change the html DOM element.
outerHTML is this

```
<div class="form-control text-control font-b6" data-langs="14">
    <div value="Auto_AFS_11213" autocomplete="off" placeholder="" maxlength="80" tabindex="0" class="truncate-container" style="min-height: 0px;">
        <div class="truncate" data-lines="1" data-test-text="Auto_AFS_11213" data-test-id="" style="--line-clamp: 1;">
            <div class="highlighter">Auto_AFS_11213</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here, what I want to do is replace that Auto_RFS_41186 text to Auto_CFS_12312.
When I tried clear() on all div elements I got this error message "cy.clear() failed because it requires a valid clearable element."
I tried all of these following but not worked:

- .clear({force: true})
- .type('{selectall}{backspace}')
- .focus() / .focused().clear()
- .click().clear()
- .invoke('val', '')

please help me remove that text. Thanks!

Comment: You will need to provide details of what a user does, there will be a sequence of events. Or state the library your app is using to implement the form.

Answer (score 4):

The error message tells you

> A clearable element matches ... `[contenteditable]`

This attribute is applicable to `<div>` (which you have).

Add the attribute to make `cy.clear()` work on a `<div>`.

```js
cy.contains('Auto_AFS_11213')
  .should('exist')
  .then($el => $el.attr('contenteditable', true))
  .clear()

cy.contains('Auto_AFS_11213')
  .should('not.to.exist')
```

This is an expedient way to get passed the issue, presuming the test is not about editing and this is just to arrange the scenario for the actual test.

---

If you goal is to **test the editing** of the form, your steps should be to replicate what a user needs to do to clear the field and enter data, etc (be it click, dbl-click, whatever).

It would be trivial to find out what actions are required if you have the live page.

Comment: Hello @Bristow. Yes my goal is to test editing.need to clear the field and add text or replace the text. Is that possible to do it to div element?